# Varieties acted upon faithfully by an abelian variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, abelian-varieties, automorphism-groups

Let  $X$ be a smooth projective variety over the complex numbers. Suppose that some positive-dimensional abelian variety  $A$ acts faithfully on $X$.

Examples of such varieties $X$ are provided by products of abelian varieties with other varieties.

Are there any other examples?

Comment: Just to be clear, is $A$ supposed to be over the complex numbers too? There are interesting examples where $A$ is defined over a function field, but I guess that isn't what you want.

Comment: Standard construction: Let $G$ be a finite subgroup of $A$ acting freely on a variety $Y$. Then $G$ (resp. $A$) acts on $A\times Y$ by the diagonal action (resp. translation on $A$), and these actions commute so $A$ acts on $X:=A\times Y/G$, and it is easy to see that this action is free. Moreover, if you choose $Y$ so that every morphism $Y\to A$ is constant (e.g. $Y$ rational) then there is no $A$-equivariant morphism $X\to A$, and in particular $X$ is not a product $A\times Z$.